# changing an integer to money format without changing the cout function

Tags: c++

I have an integer carCost that i need to display in money format ie 3700.00
however we arent supposed to alter the code where it prints.

```
TODO: Make the quote lines below print to look like money



// Example 3.45234 should be --> 3.45
// Think about iomanip
// ---------------------------------------
// Put some code in here
// ---------------------------------------
static_cast<double>(carCost);
static_cast<double>(upgradeCost);



// ---------------------------------------
// ============================================================
// Don't mess with these lines ================================
// ============================================================
std::cout << "[" << quoteNumber++ << "] "; // Don't touch me
std::cout << " Car($" << carCost << ")"; // Don't touch me
std::cout << " E(" << engineLevel << ")"; // Don't touch me
std::cout << " T(" << tireLevel << ")"; // Don't touch me
std::cout << " R(" << rimLevel << ")"; // Don't touch me
std::cout << " P(" << paintLevel << ")"; // Don't touch me
std::cout << " M(" << mufflerLevel << ")"; // Don't touch me
// Don't touch the following line -- HOWEVER, you should put
// something in the space ABOVE to make this line print like money
std::cout << " Upgrades($" << upgradeCost << ")" << std::endl; // Don't touch me
// ============================================================
```

I tried changing them using static_cast but that still doesnt resolve how to alter the format without touching the cout lines.

Comment: Why can't you change stream settings?

Comment: I dont know but the code specifically states do not touch me and "dont touch the following line--However, you should put something in the space above to make this line print like money. so somehow the value carCost gets changed from 3700 to 3700.00 and then in the line std::cout << " Car($" << carCost << ")"; // Don't touch me  it prints out 3700.00

Comment: FYI, the value `3700` **is** the value `3700.00`, just formatted differently. "Changing the value" will not affect the output format.

Comment: Tell your teacher to be meaningful assignments tbh. But the answer is `std::cout <<std::setprecision(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <iomanip>` to your `#include`s and you can use

`std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);`

before the line.

Comment: that did it thank you. i thought 'fixed' and 'setprecision' had to be applied to the individual variables with cout. i didnt know you could use like a blanket statement. thanks everyone